# Char outside of view

Tags: laravel, view, char

I have a problem with an unwanted character which is visible at the top of my page. It is not in any views because I tried a request which should return an empty view. This still returned only this one "c" character. This same issue also occurs when I use [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) or controllers.
I.e. I get 'chello world' instead of 'hello world'.
How can I find out where this character originated from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to find the file which you accidentally typed in the character `c`. A good place to start would be to do a grep / project-wide find for `c<?` as this usually would be before the opening php tag, possible `?>c`.

Example grep command
`grep -R 'c<?' /path/to/project/root`

You could also try things like `shift + ctrl + f` (Find in Project) in Atom Editor or similar editors have their version.

If you cannot find it, you could use this grep command to find all lines which begin with the character `c`

`grep -R '^c' /path/to/project/root`

The `^` means starts with.

Edit: I would suggest specifying likely offending paths first so you do not search folders such as vendors, node_modules etc. So for example use `grep -R '^c' /path/to/project/app/Controllers` and then `grep -R '^c' /path/to/project/config/` and so on and so forth

Comment: if the project is version controlled (e.g. git), then looking at the changes using `git status` may expose the `c`

Comment: I find it into web.php. Thx